# How to detect blur event on child component in parent

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild, event-binding

i'm working on an angular project and i have problem setting validation error message in a field. i want to set error class when component is touched and model is invalid.

i've tried to put event (blur) on the child component and event inside the html of the child component.

```
<!--parent-->
<form #formGlobal="ngForm>
<child-component (modelChange)="syncWithHiden()" ></child-component>
<input type="hidden" #data="ngModel">
</form>
```

```
<!--child component-->
<form>
<ng-select></ng-select>
</form>
```

i want to set hidden input #data dirty or touched when user click on ng-select and leave empty the value

Comment: maybe instead of using `(blur)` you should use `[ngModel]="var"` and `(ngModelChagne)="processEvent(data)"`

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to handle an event that occurs in a child from the parent is to create an output event in the child that is emitted when the event you want to handle occurs, which is then handled from the parent.

Basically,

child.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <form>
      <ng-select (blur)="internalEventHandler(data)">....</ng-select>
    </form>  
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class ChildComponent  {
  @Output() event = new EventEmitter();

  internalEventHandler = (dataToOutput: any) => this.event.emit(dataToOutput);
}
```

parent.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <form #formGlobal="ngForm>
      <child-component (event)="handleChildEvent($event)"></child-component>
      <input type="hidden" #data="ngModel">
    </form>
  `,
  styles: []
})

export class ParentComponent  {
  handleChildEvent = (dataFromChild) => {
    //do stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that ng-select not reacting to blur event

Comment: then your question shouldn't be related to parent-child component but ng-select itself

Comment: According to the [ng-select documentation](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select), blur event should work as `(blur): Fired on select blur`

Comment: If you are having issues getting the `blur` event to fire while using `ng-select`, that should be asked in a separate question. My answer assumes that the component `ng-select` correctly fires a `blur` event.